# Argmax statement evaluation Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I have the following pseudocode:

```
for j = 0 to argmax {l where t mod 2^l = 0} do
```

t is a counter being incremented outside of this for loop. My question is how to evaluate the argmax statement?

[image]

I believe the 'i' in the code to be a typo. 't' is probably correct.

Comment: Count the number of times you can divide t by 2 until t%2==1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no closed-form `argmax` function.

Argmax says **find** the parameter (argument) that *maximizes* the function.

Which can be arbitrarily complex, if you have a complex expression inside of the statement.

Here, it can maybe be implemented as a one-liner mathematical expression, the authors were just too lazy to spell out because of line length. Otherwise, if you have a finite integer domain, you can implement it using a loop:

```
def argmaximod2l(maxl, i):
  for l in range(maxl, 0, -1):
    if i % (2**l) == 0: return l
  raise Exception("No l was divisible by i.")
```

if you have two integers, you can use nested loops; and if your parameters a doubles and you have a smooth convex function, you can use gradient descent methods.

In this particular case, the maximum `l` should be the number of trailing zeroes of `i`. There are much more efficient methods (there might also be a library function, e.g. `Long.numberOfLeadingZeros` in Java) available.

In this particular case, you might want to implement the loop as:

```
for (int j=0, i=t; (i&1)==0; j++, i>>>=1) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if I am getting the gist of your question?

```
for (int j = 0; j < argmax; j++) {...}
```

So as argmax is a function, then

```
for (int j = 0; j < argmax(); j++) {...}

private int argmax () {return some int}
```

Comment: Argmax is not a variable. It is a mathematic expression

Answer (score 1):

Rather than implementing argmax as a function, or even computing the argmax directly, I think it would be simpler to just do this:

```
int j=0;
for(int s=t*2; s%2==0; s/=2){
  // loop code goes here
  j++;
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't be infinite unless you start with t=0, which you shouldn't according to the algorithm posted.